# Iterate Table Column By ID Instead Of Index

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

Alright, so I've got a small issue on my WordPress site, that hopefully someone can help me with. As you will see, I am using a fair amount of JavaScript to style my site. The main functions will:

1. Read a hidden "Level Status Preference" table and capture a "Critical Threshold" and "Low Threshold"
2. Iterate through the main table and compares the "% Full" column with the "Thresholds" it captured in the previous step, and styles it accordingly. (Changes the text in the "Level Status" column + prepends a small status icon next to the % value.
3. Counts the amount of "Tanks" in each "Level Status"
4. Does a few other checks to make sure the user is using Google Chrome, is on the correct page, has their defaults setup and still styles the page / reminds the user to do that if they dont, etc.

**My goal, is to not only clean up this code a little, but mainly figure out how to style based off the column-name, rather than the index:**

What I have currently, will work for now. But I will be adding a feature to let users re-order the columns, so I will need to find another way to do this.

I currently have this for reading the table rows:

```
jQuery('#table_5 tbody tr').each(function (i, row) {
    var pct = row.cells[8].innerHTML;
    console.log(pct);
```

I would like to have something like this:

```
jQuery('#table_5 tbody tr').each(function (i, row) {
    var pct = row.cells["column-pct_value"].innerHTML;
    console.log(pct);
```

This is what my custom.js file looks like at the moment. I am still fairly new to JavaScript, so I would love any feedback/suggestions. Thanks!

```
var isChrome;
if ((isChrome != !!window.chrome) && (window.location.href === "https://account.levelvision.net/login")) {
    alert("This site was built using Google Chrome. Certain features may not be available on different browsers.");
} else {

    // Initialize The Level Counters
    var criticalCount = 0;
    var lowCount = 0;
    var normalCount = 0;

    // Initialize The Default Level Status
    var critical = 15;
    var low = 30;

    jQuery(window).load(function () {

        // If user doesnt have a default set-up yet, change their defaults to 15 and 30
        if ((window.location.href === "https://account.levelvision.net/") && jQuery("#table_78_row_0 .column-criticalthreshold").text() == '') {
            alert("Looks like you don't have your defaults set up yet! Certain features will not be available until you do this. Close this alert and click the 'Tank Level Preferences' button to continue.");
            critical = 15;
            low = 30;
        }

        // If user enters a bigger critical value than low value, set them back to defaults
        if ((window.location.href === "https://account.levelvision.net/account/mytab/?updated=account") && jQuery("#table_78_row_0 .column-criticalthreshold").text() >= jQuery("#table_78_row_0 .column-lowthreshold").text()) {
            alert("Your Critical Threshold Is Larger Than Your Low Threshold. Please Update Your Values And Try Again.");
            critical = 15;
            low = 30;
        } else if ((window.location.href === "https://account.levelvision.net/") && jQuery("#table_78_row_0 .column-criticalthreshold").text() != '') {
            low = parseFloat(jQuery("#table_78_row_0 .column-lowthreshold").text());
            critical = parseFloat(jQuery("#table_78_row_0 .column-criticalthreshold").text());
        }

        console.warn(critical);
        console.warn(low);

        if (window.location.href === "https://account.levelvision.net/") {
            ColorTanksTable(); //this colors the first loaded page.
        } else if (window.location.href === "https://account.levelvision.net/demo/") {
            ColorTanksTable();
        } else if ((window.location.href === "https://account.levelvision.net/tank-details/") && (table = wpDataTables.table_1)) {
            ColorReadsTable();
        } else {
            console.warn("No Table Found");
        }

    });

    function ColorTanksTable() {
        jQuery('#table_5 tbody tr').each(function (i, row) {
            var pct = row.cells[8].innerHTML; //8
            console.log(pct);

            if (pct <= 0) {
                criticalCount++;
                console.log("Empty");
                jQuery(row.cells[9]).html("Empty");
                jQuery(row.cells[8]).css("background", "");
                jQuery(row.cells[8]).prepend('<img width="20px" height="20px" align="left" src="https://account.levelvision.net/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/Empty.png"/>');
            }

            if (pct > 0 && pct <= critical) {
                criticalCount++;
                console.log("Critical");
                jQuery(row.cells[9]).html("Critical");
                jQuery(row.cells[8]).css("background", "");
                jQuery(row.cells[8]).prepend('<img width="20px" height="20px" align="left" src="https://account.levelvision.net/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/Critical.png"/>');
            }

            console.log(critical + " < " + pct + " && " + pct + " <= " + low);
            if (critical < pct && pct <= low) {
                lowCount++;
                console.log("Low");
                jQuery(row.cells[9]).html("Low");
                jQuery(row.cells[8]).css("background", "");
                jQuery(row.cells[8]).prepend('<img width="20px" height="20px" align="left" src="https://account.levelvision.net/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/Low.png"/>');
            }

            if (pct > low && pct < 100) {
                normalCount++;
                console.log("Normal");
                jQuery(row.cells[9]).html("Normal");
                jQuery(row.cells[8]).css("background", "");
                jQuery(row.cells[8]).prepend('<img width="20px" height="20px" align="left" src="https://account.levelvision.net/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/Normal.png"/>');
            }

            if (pct >= 100) {
                normalCount++;
                console.log("Full");
                jQuery(row.cells[9]).html("Full");
                jQuery(row.cells[8]).css("background", "");
                jQuery(row.cells[8]).html("100");
                jQuery(row.cells[8]).prepend('<img width="20px" height="20px" align="left" src="https://account.levelvision.net/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/Full.png"/>');
            }

            console.log("Critical Count: " + criticalCount);
            console.log("Low Count: " + lowCount);
            console.log("Normal Count: " + normalCount);

            jQuery('#table_3 tbody tr').each(function (i, row) {
                jQuery(row.cells[0]).html(criticalCount);
                jQuery(row.cells[1]).html(lowCount);
                jQuery(row.cells[2]).html(normalCount);
            })
        });
    }

    function ColorReadsTable() {
        jQuery('#table_1 tbody tr').each(function (i, row) {
            var pct = row.cells[1].innerHTML;
            console.log(pct);

            if (pct <= 0) {
                console.log("Empty");
                jQuery(row.cells[9]).html("Empty");
                jQuery(row.cells[1]).css("background", "");
                jQuery(row.cells[1]).prepend('<img width="20px" height="20px" align="left" src="https://account.levelvision.net/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/Empty.png"/>');
            }

            if (pct > 0 && pct <= critical) {
                console.log("Critical");
                jQuery(row.cells[9]).html("Critical");
                jQuery(row.cells[1]).css("background", "");
                jQuery(row.cells[1]).prepend('<img width="20px" height="20px" align="left" src="https://account.levelvision.net/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/Critical.png"/>');
            }

            console.log(critical + " < " + pct + " && " + pct + " <= " + low);
            if (critical < pct && pct <= low) {
                console.log("Low");
                jQuery(row.cells[9]).html("Low");
                jQuery(row.cells[1]).css("background", "");
                jQuery(row.cells[1]).prepend('<img width="20px" height="20px" align="left" src="https://account.levelvision.net/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/Low.png"/>');
            }

            if (pct > low && pct < 100) {
                console.log("Normal");
                jQuery(row.cells[9]).html("Normal");
                jQuery(row.cells[1]).css("background", "");
                jQuery(row.cells[1]).prepend('<img width="20px" height="20px" align="left" src="https://account.levelvision.net/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/Normal.png"/>');
            }

            if (pct >= 100) {
                console.log("Full");
                jQuery(row.cells[9]).html("Full");
                jQuery(row.cells[1]).css("background", "");
                jQuery(row.cells[1]).html("100");
                jQuery(row.cells[1]).prepend('<img width="20px" height="20px" align="left" src="https://account.levelvision.net/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/Full.png"/>');
            }
        });
    }
}
```

[image: Example of my homepage I want styled]

Comment: can you create demo code with html ?

Comment: My table is JSON based, so it might just be easier to PM you some credentials for a demo account on my site if that would be easier?

Comment: Questions on Stack Overflow must be self-contained and contain all relevant information so that all users can see it to be able to help, and also so that the question is useful to users in future. DMing information is discouraged. Please see how to create a [MRE] that we can use to can reproduce what you are doing and be able to help.

Comment: Not really sure if this will be of any help, but I created a jsfiddle with some test data, and the small bit of code I would like to change: https://jsfiddle.net/cjo243v6/

Answer (score 0):

For some reason my first answer was deleted, but this is the solution I've got working now if anyone else has the same question:

```
jQuery('#table_5 tbody tr').each(function (i, row) {
    var pct = jQuery(this).find(".column-pct_value").text();
    console.log(pct);
```

If anyone else has a better alternative, I'd love to hear it!