# Iterate table column using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

For my WordPress site, I am using a bit of JavaScript to help style my table on page load. So far, I am able to iterate a specific column in my table, but only by using its index. I was wondering if there was any way to do this same thing, but use the columns name/ID instead of its index?

I currently have this for reading the "Percent Full" column in my table:

```
jQuery('#table_5 tbody tr').each(function (i, row) {
    var pct = row.cells[8].innerHTML;
    console.log(pct);
```

I would like to have something like this:

```
jQuery('#table_5 tbody tr').each(function (i, row) {
    var pct = row.cells["column-pct_value"].innerHTML;
    console.log(pct);
```

Ive been trying to work out the correct syntax, but can't seem to get it quite right... Is something like this possible? Or am I wasting my time on this?

[image]

Comment: Could you include an example of your table your markup?  Without it it is hard to know if you are properly traversing it with your JS.

Comment: You can use `var pct = $(this).find("td:eq(8)").text()` where `this` current `tr` which is been iterate.

Comment: Here is a link to a less simplified version of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63690962/iterate-table-column-by-id-instead-of-index

Comment: Thanks for the help Swati... Had a little trouble trying to decipher what exactly your comment was trying to say at first, but after seeing a couple other people use similar examples, I think I understand what you were trying to get at!

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else has the same question, this is what I've got working now:

```
jQuery('#table_5 tbody tr').each(function (i, row) {
    var pct = jQuery(this).find(".column-pct_value").text();
    console.log(pct);
```

If anyone else has a better alternative, I'd love to hear it!